# Angular Service Worker (ngsw) or Workbox

Tags: angular, workbox, angular-service-worker, ngsw-config

Please let me ask a question.

Firstly,I would like to build angular progressive web app.
And I found that I can use angular native service worker (ngsw) or also framework-agnostic library called Workbox to build progressive web app.
Which approach is easier to start with, which library is simpler to use, and which resulting PWA is more convenient to maintain.
Which library should I use ,please advice me(**ngsw** or  **workbox**)
Please can somebody explain with pros and cons.

Comment: This video goes into some detail about the two options: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YQcF4Vl7MU

Answer (score 1):

I took this information from the [International Javascript Conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YQcF4Vl7MU) and the [Angular University](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/).

Both have been created for the same purpose, to implement a service worker in your projects, **ngsw** is easier and **workbox** is more configurable.

#### Angular Service Worker (ngsw)

- Easy to start `ng add @angular/pwa --project <name of project as in angular.json>`
- Seamless integration with angular
- Coding-free basic features
- Angular-friendly approach

In a sentence...

> **ngsw** is everything the Angular team thinks a project needs to implement a service worker.

#### Workbox

- Framework-agnostic `npm install workbox-build --save-dev`
- Rich functionality
- Maximum flexible configuration
- Full power of your own service worker

In a sentence...

> **workbox** helps you create a fully configurable service worker. It's like ngsw but on steroids.